# Alphanumeric ID in sequelize.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js, alphanumeric

I'm using sequelizejs with PostgreSQL as ORM in my webapp, I want to use alphanumeric ID instead numeric.How can I do that ?
Is there some way to do it through sequelize? 
Or do I want to generate this id separately and then save it into db ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: As far as I know - you have to generate it. If there's another option - please let me know! :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a UUID as primary key, and set its default value to uuidv1 or v4

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/datatypes/#uuid

```
id: {
  type: DataTypes.UUID,
  defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
  primaryKey: true
}
```